# Hash indexes with conditions in PG10

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I am using Postgresql 10, and i have the table of following structure:

```
primary_key_id;....;foreign_key_id
```

`foreign_key_id` field is bigint ascending not null field and i had an hash index on it. It was too big and i have decided to create two partial indexes with condition `foreign_key_id > <SOME_VALUE>` and `foreign_key_id <= <SOME_VALUE>` and put index with "old" data to another tablespace.

I have successfully created them, but their sizes are practically the same (17Gb vs 19Gb), but in new indexes must be very few data.

What am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same "new" B-TREE index size - 8MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAMkU%3D1x0k%2BdRQHDUgp4BjFeSgxyLBBXyKNY5Pt1Yu6YHB0mhKA%40mail.gmail.com) which has never been fixed.  Hash indexes estimate an initial size, but don't take the partial nature into account when doing so and so way overestimate that initial size.  Why not just use the default (btree) index?